# Jordan form of the exponential of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation, jordan-normal-form

Given a matrix $A$ which has the form of a Jordan normal matrix:

$$ A = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\log(\phi_1) & 1& ...& 0\\
  & \log( \phi_2)& & \\
 &   &  \ddots & 1 \\
0 & & & \log (\phi_n) \\
\end{array}\right)$$

how can we prove that the Jordan normal form of $ \exp(A)= VJV^{-1} $ is $J$:

$$ J = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\phi_1 & 1& ...& 0\\
  &  \phi_2& & \\
 &   &  \ddots & 1 \\
0 & & &  \phi_n \\
\end{array}\right)$$

that has the exact same block form as $A$, but only with the exponential of the eigenvalues?

EDIT:

I tried the $2 \times 2$ case to see if it worked and this is what I got:

$$ A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\log(\phi_1) & 1\\
 0 & \log( \phi_2) \\
\end{array}\right)$$

We can separate this into to $2$ matricies:

$$ A =  \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\log(\phi_1) & 0\\
 0 & \log( \phi_2) \\
\end{array}\right) 
+
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1\\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

Exponentiating:

$$ e^A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\phi_1 & 0\\
 0 & \phi_2 \\
\end{array}\right)
 \times
\left[I + \left(\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1\\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)  \right]
= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\phi_1  & \phi_1\\
 0 & \phi_2  \\
\end{array}\right)$$

Now, its eigenvalues have all algebraic multiplicity of 1 so the Jordan normal form of $e^A$ is:

$$ J = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\phi_1  & 0\\
 0 & \phi_2 \\
\end{array}\right)$$

which is not quite what we wanted, I dont know what to do.

Comment: The $2 \times 2$ matrix A is not in Jordan normal form unless $\log(\phi_1) = \log(\phi_2)$.

Comment: Thats right, thank you! I can justify the $n \times n$ case by saying it easily generalises for higher dimensions, only the caculations get more tedious correct ?

Comment: There is a nice and explicit way to calculate in the $n \times n$ case.

Comment: This answer describes how to calculate $f(A)$ when $f$ is a power series and $A$ is a matrix, using Jordan form: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803365/analytical-function-of-a-matrix-equivalence-of-the-definitions/2821063#2821063

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: If $J$ is the $n\times n$ Jordan block with zero eigenvalue, compute the kernel of $exp(J)$.

Comment: I cant get there

Comment: Can you write down the matrix of $exp(J)$ if $J$ is the standard Jordan block?

Comment: I edited the question, I dont know what I did wrong

Comment: By the "standard Jordan block" I mean the $n \times n$ block with eigenvalue $0$.